# print stars as much as the values in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, nested-loops

I'm trying to make a C++ program start creating an array and takes the values from the user , then print every value + star as much the value is .. Example : the user had entered 5 then the output must be like this 
5***** 
Input

1

2

3

4

5

6

output

1*

2**

3***

4****
and so on

.. help :(

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
void main() 
{
    int arr[10]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i]; 
        int x = arr[i]; 
        for (int j = 0; x <= arr[i]; j++)
        {
            cout<< "*";
        }
    }
}
```

And another help please can you give me some useful link to practice on programming to be professional

Comment: You should have perfected the "print five stars" part before you entangled it with an array and an input loop. **Develop new functions in isolation.**

Comment: When you have a problem, it is always advisable to state what you got, and what you were expecting, rather than having people interpret your code for you.

Comment: `x <= arr[i]` -> `j < arr[i]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Use the following code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main()  {
  int arr[10]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
   cin >> arr[i]; 
   int x = arr[i]; 
   for (int j = 0; j < x; j++){ // your condition was wrong

   cout<< "*";
  }
   cout<<endl; // for better formatting
 }
 return 0;
}
```

**For edited question**

```
int main()  {
int arr[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];


}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int x = arr[i];
    cout << x;
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++){ // your condition was wrong

        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: o sorry man the program must be like this input 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 , then print like this 1* next line 2** next line 3*** and so on ,, first take all the value then print them

Comment: `int main()` may also be a thing to fix. At least clang++ doesn't like void.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, you are right. `void main` is not portable and bad practice. edited.

Comment: Input

1

2

3

4

5

6

output

1*

2**

3***

4**** and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
void main() 
{
    int nbValues = 10;
    int arr[nbValues];

    // First recover the values
    for (int i = 0; i < nbValues; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    // Then print the output
    for (int i = 0; i < nbValues; i++)
    {
        int x = arr[i];
        cout << x;// Print the number
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            cout<< "*";// Then print the stars
        }
        cout << endl;// Then new line
    }
}
```